# Gregwar Captcha error in symfony 2.1.7

Tags: php, captcha, symfony-2.1

I installed the GregwarCaptcha bundle and add the following code in controller

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->add('captcha', 'captcha', array(
                            'width' => 200,
                            'height' => 50,
                            'length' => 6,
                        ));
    return $this->render('MyIndexBundle:Default:contact.html.twig',array(
                      'form' => $form->createView()

                    ));
```

the following code in template

```
{% form_theme form 'MyIndexBundle:Default:captcha.html.twig' %}
 <form action="" method="post">
   ........
  {{ form_widget(form.captcha) }}
  .......
   </form>
```

and the captcha.html.twig is

```
{% block captcha_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
 <img src="{{ captcha_code }}" alt="" title="captcha" width="{{ captcha_width }}" height="{{ captcha_height }}" />
 ...
 {{ form_widget(form, {'attr': { 'autocapitalize': 'off','autocorrect': 'off' }}) }}
  ...
 {% endspaceless %}
 {% endblock %}
```

i am getting "Method "captcha" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist" error.
 ...if i use captcha.html.twig, directily i get captcah-code does not exist...

Comment: Isn't the recursion the problem? In the block that should render the widget you call `form_widget` with the form being rendered as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

I manage using gregwar captcha using it like this :

First, Add `new Gregwar\CaptchaBundle\GregwarCaptchaBundle(),` to your `AppKernel.php`

Then  Add the folowwing code on `config.yml`

```
gregwar_captcha:
  width: 200
  height: 50
  length: 6
```

Then, Add `->add('captcha', 'captcha')` to your `$builder`

Finally, Add `{{ form_widget(form.captcha) }}` in twig template.

So I didn't use `form_theme` neither `captcha.html.twig`

And this is working just fine.

Comment: I've just tryed with theming. `{% form_theme form with '::captcha.html.twig' %}` and this is working too. I've noticed that in your code you forget the "with" when using `form_theme`. And another difference i didn't put `, {'attr': { 'autocapitalize': 'off','autocorrect': 'off' }}`on theming. Hope that will help you.